# How can I read the parquet dictionary in java

Tags: dictionary, parquet

I have seen that parquet format uses dictionaries to store some columns and that these dictionaries can be used to speed up the filters if `useDictionaryFilter()` is used on the `ParquetReader`.

Is there any way to access these dictionaries from java code ?
I'd like to use them to create a list of distinct members of my column and though that it would be faster to read only the dictionary values than scanning the whole column.

I have looked into `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader` API but did not found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods in `org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary` allow you to:

- Query the range of dictionary indexes: Between 0 and [getMaxId()](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/column/Dictionary.java#L38).
- Look up the entry corresponding to any index, for example for an int field you can use [decodeToInt()](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/e9e36cdc44a68662885e35773187cca00d20239e/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/column/Dictionary.java#L44).

Once you have a `Dictionary`, you can iterate over all indexes to get all entries, so the question boils down to getting a `Dictionary`. To do that, use [ColumnReaderImpl](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/e9e36cdc44a68662885e35773187cca00d20239e/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/column/impl/ColumnReaderImpl.java#L339) as a guide:

```
getDictionary(ColumnDescriptor path, PageReader pageReader) {
  DictionaryPage dictionaryPage = pageReader.readDictionaryPage();
  if (dictionaryPage != null) {
    Dictionary dictionary = dictionaryPage.getEncoding().initDictionary(path, dictionaryPage);
  }
}
```

Please note that a column chunk may contain a mixture of data pages, some dictionary-encoded and some not, because if the dictionary "gets full" (reaches the maximum allowed size), then the writer outputs the dictionary page and the dictionary-encoded data pages and switches to not using dictionary-encoding for the rest of the data pages.